# LINQ to NHibernate and let keyword

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is this possible to use let keyword with nhibernate linq?
I wrote

```
 var posts = from post in postsRepository.GetPosts(name)
             let commentsCount = (from c in NHUnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Linq<Comment>()
                                  where c.Post.ID == post.ID
                                  select c).Count()
             select new ...
```

and in response I have

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: post of: Sys.Domain.Entities.Post

Comment: Presumably your comment is linked to your post? couldn't you use a group operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with mapping of `Comment.Post`